# Perform segue after assync call IOS

Tags: ios, xcode4.3, segue

I want to perform a segue, after a assync call to a service.

In one class I make the call, and I receive it.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(){
            NSLog(@"json arrived");
            SearchViewController *searchVCObj =[[SearchViewController alloc]init];
                     [searchVCObj performSegueSinceInfoCamed:sender];
        });
```

Now i want to perform a segue in another class i put:

```
-(IBAction)performSegueSinceInfoCamed:(id)sender
{  
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MySegue" sender:self];
}
```

But i get an error: "NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver () has no segue with identifier 'MySegue''"

Witch is "false" since it exist.

Can you help me?

Comment: Do you have "MySegue" set as the Identifier of the segue in question in your storyboard?

Comment: Yes I do. I really don.t know what is happening

Comment: In fact. If I call that:

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MySegue" sender:self];

On a button the segue is performed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create a segue directly between controllers, not from a UIButton to a ViewController.  Then the segue will exist on the controller and can be called by it's identifier.

Comment: TKS a lot! You helped me a lot!

Comment: What is the solution for it ?